# A-Frame Trigger javascript function on collide with camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aframe

I am trying to trigger my score function whenever the camera collide or touch an object like:

```
<a-entity id="rock" static-body obj-model="obj:models/rock_mesh.obj;mtl:images/rock_mesh.mtl" rotation="0 90 0" position="7.30242379045994 0.3 0">
     </a-entity>
```

I equip my a score text on my camera:

```
 <a-text id="score" value="0" position="-0.2 -0.5 -1" color="red" width="5" anchor="left"></a-text>
```

And trying to trigger a function like this:

```
let score = 0;
score = score + 1
$("#score").setAttribute('text','value','Score '+score)
```

This is just a draft up code, I am still new to javascript

How can i do this? Incrementing the score on the screen whenever my camera touches this "rock" object?

How can i detect the collision or touch with the object and my camera?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to detect collisions would be detecting if the THREE bounding boxes are overlapping

You can use Ngo Kevins [aabb-collider](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider/) which emits `hitstart` upon collision. Remember though, the camera does not have it's own geometry:

```
<a-camera foo geometry="primitive: box" aabb-collider="objects: a-box"></a-camera>
<a-box scale="2 2 2" class="box" color="blue" position="0 1.6 -5" ></a-box>
```

with foo being a simple event listener for `hitstart`.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
     this.el.addEventListener("hitstart", (e)=>{
         // Collision ! increment the score
     })
  }
})
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/54g3hf6j/).

If possible, I wouldn't detect collisions with your model, but create some collision boxes.

---

It's also worth mentioning, if You'd want to use a [physics engine](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system) in your project, Don McCurdys Physics System also enables [collision detection](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system#collisions). Instead of `hitstart`, You'd need to listen for `collision`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
score++;
$("#score").attr("value", score);
```

Comment: how do i detect the collision or touch with the object, so i can call the function afterward

Comment: Look at the above answer